# Identifying consonants/vowels in R string

Tags: r, string, gsub, sqldf

Can't seem to find an answer for this.

I have written some R code to extract a substring from a longer string, taking every character left of the '.' from the original string, as below.

```
dataframe1[["column"]] <- gsub("\\..*","",dataframe2$variable)
```

This works fine, no problem. **NOTE** the resultant substrings are of variable length between 5-7 chars.

I now need to find a way of evaluating whether each character in said string is a consonant or a vowel.

I had achieved this previously using sqldf as follows;

```
   ("SELECT char1||char2||char3||char4||char5 as pattern
            FROM
                (SELECT CASE WHEN substr(var,1,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') THEN 'V' ELSE 'C' END as char1  
                ,CASE WHEN substr(var,2,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') THEN 'V' ELSE 'C' END as char2  
                ,CASE WHEN substr(var,3,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') THEN 'V' ELSE 'C' END as char3
                ,CASE WHEN substr(var,4,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') THEN 'V' ELSE 'C' END as char4
                ,CASE WHEN substr(var,5,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') THEN 'V' ELSE 'C' END as char5 
     FROM some_table WHERE len = '5L')")
```

This would give me something like:

ABBCD || VCCCC

ABABE || VCVCV

AEEBC || VVVCC

etc etc...

The problem is this is totally inelegant and woefully inefficient, particularly as, as mentioned, the length of the var is between 5-7 chars.
I also want to avoid incorporating sqldf as I've found it makes performing base R functions on the dataframe later difficult in certain situations.

So, can you please advise as to how I can achieve this using R and importantly, using a method that works irrespective of char length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
a <- "stackoverflow"

b <- gsub("[^aeiouAEIOU]","C",a)
b <- gsub("[^C]","V",b)

b
[1] "CCVCCVCVCCCVC"
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Gustar, how would I apply this to every string in the column however?

Comment: Just replace `a` with `df$var` (or whatever), and it should work for a vector of values without further adjustment.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work fine.
Am I right in thinking that the regex `b <- gsub("[^aeiouAEIOU]","C",a)` is basically "if not any of 'AEIOU' then 'C'" and subsequently that `b <- gsub("[^C]","V",b)` is "if not 'C', then 'V'"

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help brother. All the best!